# How to prove that this function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, continuity

If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on the rectangle $R=[a,b] \times [c,d]$, prove that the function
$g(x) := \int\limits_{c}^{d} f(x,y) dy$
is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in [a,b]$, then $|g(x) - g(t)| \leq \int_c^d |f(x,y) - f(t,y)| dy$.  Now given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|(x,y) - (t,x)| < \delta$ then $|f(x,y) - f(t,y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{d-c}$.

Comment: thanks! i see why $d-c$ helps to make $g$ being continuous, addition to @Mhenni Benghorbal's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance. We need to prove that

> $\forall \epsilon >0 $ thers exists $\delta$ such that
>
> $$ |h|<\delta \implies |g(x+h) - g(x)| < \epsilon $$

We advance as

$$ g(x+h) - g(x)= \int\limits_{c}^{d} f(x+h,y) dy - \int\limits_{c}^{d} f(x,y) dy $$

$$  = \int\limits_{c}^{d} (f(x+h,y)  - f(x,y)) dy $$

$$ \implies |g(x+h) - g(x)| =\Bigg| \int\limits_{c}^{d} (f(x+h,y)  - f(x,y)) dy \Bigg| $$

$$\implies |g(x+h) - g(x)| \leq  \int\limits_{c}^{d} |f(x+h,y)  - f(x,y)| dy. $$

You need to use the fact that the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ to finish the problem.

Comment: @PandaMan: You are welcome.